# Setting Email body in php variable inside while loop Not working

Tags: php

So i am trying to send confirmation of an order via email. To do this i need to attach the body as a variable which is $body

So i have all my html code inside the $body. That part works great and it emails successfully.

However i need to loop out what ever was ordered so the customer knows what they ordered and what they paid for each item.

So here is the SQL query

```
// GET THE PRODUCTS THAT HAVE BEEN ORDERED
$w="SELECT
nfw_order_new_items.name,
nfw_order_new_items.qty,
nfw_order_new_items.price
FROM
nfw_order_new_items
WHERE
nfw_order_new_items.id_order = '$order_ID'";
$ww= mysql_query("$w") or die("Inv Rows ".mysql_error());
```

Then the body as an example, has my html in it. The $name, $qty and $price are where i want my loop to create the rows of the table depending on how many in the result. I have tried putting the loop outside body like below, but that doesnt work either. See below:

```
while(list($name,$qty,$price)= mysql_fetch_row($ww)){
$body = "<table width=\"80%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">
          <tr style=\"font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#FFF\">
            <td width=\"111\" bgcolor=\"#333333\" style=\"padding-left:5px;\">Product Name:</td>
            <td width=\"290\" bgcolor=\"#333333\">QTY:</td>
            <td width=\"67\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#333333\">Price Each</td>
            <td width=\"121\" align=\"right\" bgcolor=\"#333333\" style=\"padding-right:5px; font-size:12px;  text-align:right;\">Total Price</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style=\"padding-left:5px; font-size:12px;\">$name</td>
            <td style=\"padding-left:0px; font-size:12px;\">$qty</td>
            <td style=\"padding-left:0px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;\">$price</td>
          </tr>
        </table>"; }
```

Comment: Why do you `echo` so much using PHP?

Comment: Do you have another solution?

Comment: the way you are doing is wrong, you don't have to store huge chunk of text in the variable at first place, secondly learn how to not echo too much of markup using php

Comment: Wow, thanks for the negative question with absolutely no help. You are under no obligation to help others and i dont "expect help". I appreciate any time given towards helping others and myself to learn. Everyone starts somewhere. I did do my research and i was unaware i could close it and then continue it again. But i do now and its only thanks to the people below. If you are not going to be helpful in the future dont even bother to reply and most of all dont put bad marks against a question because you think its "stupid".

Comment: I hardly down vote, check my profile and see whats the downvote and upvote ratio and then speak

Comment: And btw yea, to prove you that I didn't down voted, I will down vote now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to print the table header each time 
you can do it like below

```
$body = "<table width=\"80%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">
          <tr style=\"font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#FFF\">
            <td width=\"111\" bgcolor=\"#333333\" style=\"padding-left:5px;\">Product Name:</td>
            <td width=\"290\" bgcolor=\"#333333\">QTY:</td>
            <td width=\"67\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#333333\">Price Each</td>
            <td width=\"121\" align=\"right\" bgcolor=\"#333333\" style=\"padding-right:5px; font-size:12px;  text-align:right;\">Total Price</td>
          </tr>";

while(list($name,$qty,$price)= mysql_fetch_row($ww))
{
    $body .= "<tr>
            <td style=\"padding-left:5px; font-size:12px;\">$name</td>
            <td style=\"padding-left:0px; font-size:12px;\">$qty</td>
            <td style=\"padding-left:0px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;\">$price</td>
          </tr>";
}

$body .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help. I now know i can close and then continue. I didnt know i could do that  :)

Thank you.

Comment: @Elgoots Always here to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
$body = "<table width=\"80%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tr style=\"font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#FFF\">
            <td width=\"111\" bgcolor=\"#333333\" style=\"padding-left:5px;\">Product Name:</td>
            <td width=\"290\" bgcolor=\"#333333\">QTY:</td>
            <td width=\"67\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#333333\">Price Each</td>
            <td width=\"121\" align=\"right\" bgcolor=\"#333333\" style=\"padding-right:5px; font-size:12px;  text-align:right;\">Total Price</td>
          </tr>";
while(list($name,$qty,$price)= mysql_fetch_row($ww)){
$body .= "<tr>
            <td style=\"padding-left:5px; font-size:12px;\">$name</td>
            <td style=\"padding-left:0px; font-size:12px;\">$qty</td>
            <td style=\"padding-left:0px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;\">$price</td>
          </tr>
        "; }
$body.="</table>";
```

Comment: Why to print the column names again and again in the loop.

Comment: Thank you Praveen for taking the time to reply. Your code did work  :)   however i went with Veerendra's answer. Thank you though.